# Transversality theorem for maps between fiber bundles

Tags: differential-topology, fibre-bundles, transversality

I am looking for a possible generalization of the standard Trasversality Theorem which roughly says that transverse maps are generic. For example, see the version below:
[From page 74, Theorem 2.1 in Hirsch, Differential Topology, GTM 33](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AhmS.png)

Let us modify the step-up to a more general situation. Now assume furthermore that $M,N$ are both the total spaces of fiber bundles over the same base manifold $B$. It is possible that $M,N$ have different fibers over $B$. Everything else is the same as before. Let $C^\infty(M,N,B)$ denote the space of smooth $f:M\to N$ making the following diagram commute (under strong or weak topologies, if it matters in this case):
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
M @>f>> N\\
@V  V V @VV  V\\
B @= B
\end{CD}
where the vertical maps are the bundle projections. Let $T(M,N,B;A)$ denote the subspace of those $f$ that are transverse to a submanifold $A\subseteq N$.

My question is: Are maps transverse to $A$ generic in any sense among those maps making the diagram commute? For example, is the subset $T(M,N,B;A)$ residual in $C^\infty(M,N,B)$? Could anyone guide me to a reference please?

While my intuition might lead (or mislead?) me to believe that transverse maps are always generic, I am not sure if I need to make any additional assumptions on $A$ or on the fiber bundles $M\to B$ and $N\to B$. Notice that if $B$ is a single point, then the new step-up is the same as the old one. So I am indeed asking for a generalization of the usual transversality theorem here.

In a sense, the questions above ask for a "transversality theorem parametrized by $B$". I am aware that there is a parametric transversality theorem which seems similar in spirit to what I want. But I don't think it answers my questions above.

Comment: Yes. This is not a proof, but I think it is a good outline of why it should be true: Imagine that the function space, in this case $\mathcal F=C^\infty(M,N,B)$, is an infinite-dimensional manifold and notice that the evaluation map, in this case from $\mathcal F\times M$ to $N$, is a submersion, i.e. transverse to every point, and is therefore transverse to every submanifold of $N$.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Thanks! I can see that the evaluation map $\mathcal{F}\times M\to N$ is a submersion. But I fail to see how that conclusion can give me a single $f\in\mathcal{F}$ that is transverse to a submanifold in $N$. I might miss a simple point. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Here's the rest of the story. Pretend that $\mathcal F$ is actually a manifold. Since the evaluation map $e:\mathcal F\times M\to N$ is transverse to $A$, the preimage $P=e^{-1}(A)$ is a submanifold of $\mathcal F\times M$. Now apply Sard's Theorem to the projection $p:P\to \mathcal F$. A point $f\in\mathcal F$ that is a regular value for $p$ (i.e. such that there is no critical point $x$ of $p$ such that $p(x)=f$) is the same as an $f$ such the map $m\mapsto e(f,m)$ is transverse to $A$.

Comment: In general that argument shows that if a family of maps $(f_t)$ (considered as a single smooth map from a product space) satisfies a transversality condition then for almost every point $t$ in the parametrizing manifold the corresponding map $f_t$ satisfies that condition.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Now I get the idea. Thanks for taking the time to explain it.